# Formatting strings, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: c#, string, format

I have the following code:

```
double f = (1500 / 3000);
MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0:F2}",f));
```

I expect to get `0.50` as my output but I get `0.00`. What am I doing wrong? Please help me understand how formatting works.

Comment: See [/ Operator (C# Reference) on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3b1ff23f.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are dividing integers.

Change to

```
double f  = (Convert.ToDouble(1500)/Convert.ToDouble(300);
MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0:F2}",f));
```

Comment: For number literals it's much more effecient to just add the `d` suffix.  Example `1500d`.

Answer (score 11):

It's integer division.  At least one of your values needs to be a double (non-integer).

```
1500 / 3000 = 0
1500 / 3000.0 = 0.50
```

Answer (score 2):

try `double f = (1500.0 / 3000.0);` ?

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
double f = (1500d / 3000d);
```

If you don't use "d", numbers are meant to be integer, so 1500/3000 is zero!
Almost one of the numbers you're using must be double or cast to double before division.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that the `double` value is set to `0`.  You are doing integer division which truncates the result to `0` and then assigns it to a double.  You need to switch to floating point division

```
double f = (1500d / 3000);
```